# Any way to highlight operators comparison for Objects in iOS Objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, operator-overloading, operators

Recently in a iOS project I have refactored money data type from double to NSDecimalNumber to get a rid of discrepancies caused by handling money with doubles.

The refactoring is complete but my concerns are for all those comparisons made through standard operators that are not raised as errors by the compiler because comparing objects is still valid (memory addresses are compared) but not logically correct

```
double a = 4;
double b = 3;
if(a > b) do stuff //valid and logically correct

NSDecimalNumber *a = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"4"];
NSDecimalNumber *b = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"3"];
if(a > b) do stuff  //valid but not logically correct as here the memory addresses of variables will be compared instead of values.
```

**Is there any way to make the compiler highlight these situations?** 
My first idea was to create a category for NSDecimalNumber and overloading operators so that they would work properly for them and, as it s not possible to override operators in Obj-C, I tried 2 different ways to accomplish this:

1. Creating a swift extension of NSDecimalNumber where I overload those operators (in swift it s possible to override standard operators) and then using those new methods in my Obj-c environment through Swift bridge. After some tests and have red a lot on StackOverflow it seems this approach is not possible as Obj-C will always treat standard operators in the common way (comparing addressed for objects)
2. Creating a category for NSDecimalNumber where I overload those operators though C++ that gives the option to overload operators to the programmer. The problem here is that I am not confident with C++ and I cannot find any example to address me.

**So in the end I need a way to highlight any comparison between objects made with standard operators**.

Any help is really appreciated,

Thanks.